# Using extjs5 to upload files with customized request structure

Tags: file-upload, request, customization, extjs5

I would like to upload extjs5 form data (containing a file to be uploaded!) using a customized request to the server. This is what the server expects:

```
{
   "method"    : <method name>,
   "use_json"  : <true|false>,
   "data"      : { <parameters in JSON format> }
}

e.g.

{ 
   "method"    : "foo", 
   "use_json"  : "1",
   "data"      : { 
       "param1": "bar", 
       "file"  : "myFile" 
   }
}
```

The form panel I am using contains both "fileUpload: true," as well as a "fileuploadfield" field. Once the user clicks on the submit button an event is fired, picked by the main controller and then processed by the following method:

```
sendRequest: function(sender,parameters) {

    var serverMethod = parameters.method;
    var formData     = parameters.form.getForm().getFieldValues();

    var requestData = {
        'method'    : serverMethod,
        'use_json'  : "1",
        'data'      : formData
    }; 

    Ext.Ajax.request({
        'url'     : '../../cgi-bin/cmd.cgi',
        'method'  : 'POST',
        'jsonData': requestData,
        'waitMsg' : 'Sending request...',
        'headers' : {'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8'},
        });

} //endfunction sendRequest
```

I get a server error 500 stating "Malformed multipart POST: data truncated" indicating that the request was not correctly sent to the server. This is corroborated by what the request header shows - apparently it still uses 'XMLHttpRequest' although it should not (according to extjs docs):

```
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Content-Length  161
Content-Type    multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8
Cookie  CGISESSID=9eadc8cb28eac7cc02b0a4b5895e0b41
Host    localhost:8080
Referer ...
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

So, my question is: what do I have to do to make extjs use the non-standard request for file upload together with my customized data structure?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot upload files via Ajax, that is why Ext uses hidden form and iframe behind the scenes when uploading.

See how is the [File Upload](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/ext/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Connection) process described in the documentation.

Comment: I have checked the docs back & forth and also found the paragraph on "File Upload" you mention, but I am still looking for more information of how exactly extjs handles file upload and if there is a "designed" way adjusting it to one's needs.